# Better way to form a Ruby hash dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to form a hash dynamically after checking the existence of the values. I always run into this case and form the hash as follows, but I find this very ugly, and wondered if their is a tricky or a prettier way to do this:

Here is how I am forming it:

```
args = {}
args[:pagination_token]     = params[:pagination_token] if params[:pagination_token]
args[:sort_by]              = params[:sort_by] if params[:sort_by]
args[:sort_direction]       = params[:sort_direction] if params[:sort_direction]
args[:pagination_direction] = params[:pagination_direction] if params[:pagination_direction]
args[:limit]                = params[:limit] if params[:limit]
users_list, next_pagination_token, previous_pagination_token = current_application.paginated_users(args)
```

**A better way?**

Comment: For the general case, there is no better way. This case is very specific, though. Just filtering of the original hash on presence of the value. Not even renaming the keys.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) like so:

```
args = params.slice(:pagination_token, :sort_by, :sort_direction, :pagination_direction, :limit)
```

**Edit**:

Since the question's subject says "in Ruby", and the above method will work only if your have included ActiveSupport. Which in fact will work in this case as OP is using Rails. For those who wants to do it in Ruby can do:

```
valid_params = [:pagination_token, :sort_by, :sort_direction, :pagination_direction, :limit]
args = params.select{ |k| valid_params.include? k }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ActiveSupport's `Hash#slice`:

```
args = params.slice(:pagination_token, :sort_by, :sort_direction, :pagination_direction, :limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way it can be done:

```
h = { 
       pagination_token: 100, 
       sort_by: 200, 
       # sort_direction: 300, 
       pagination_direction: 400, 
       limit: 500, 
       some_other_value: 500, 
    }

keys = [:pagination_token, :sort_by, :sort_direction]
p [keys, h.values_at(*keys)].transpose.to_h.reject {|_,v| v.nil?}
#=> {:pagination_token=>100, :sort_by=>200}
```